# How to convert a List into a number in python using recursion only

Tags: python

```
def listIntoNumber(list,base):
   //Enter code Here 
Print(listIntoNumber([1,2,3,2,9],1) # It should return 12329
```

This above method listIntoNumber needs to be completed in rescursivly

Comment: what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: what if listIntoNumber would digest a number.

Comment: What is the logic behind `base`? Should it possibly be `10` instead of `1`?

Comment: Hint: assume that you are able to convert a list of length `n`. How could you use that ability to convert a list of length `n+1`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough, if the list has one element, return it, else, multiply the first element by the base to the power of the list length minus 1 and add the output of the recursive call on the rest of the list.

*NB. I imagine you meant base **10**, base 1 doesn't really make sense ;)*

```
def listIntoNumber(lst, base):
    assert len(lst) > 0
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    return lst[0]*base**(len(lst)-1) + listIntoNumber(lst[1:], base)

print(listIntoNumber([1,2,3,2,9], 10))
# 12329

print(listIntoNumber([1,0,0,1,0], 2))
# 18
```

Comment: Does doing the homework for them really help them learn?

Comment: @JohnColeman this is not written here that is is homework, if it is (likely), there are so many possibilities to find answers anyway that it is on them not to spoil/cheat their education

Answer (score 0):

**I assume base is the current number**

```
def listIntoNumber(lst,base):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return base
    base=base+lst[0]*(10**(len(lst)-1))
    print(base)
    lst.pop(0)

    return listIntoNumber(lst,base)

print(listIntoNumber([1,2,3,2,9],0))
```

Comment: This has the side effect of destroying the original list. Also, it is more plausible that the base is the base of the target number system, although OP wasn't clear on that point.